# Unknown custom element: <v-btn> after installing vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am not sure why this isn't working.
But I have created a file in **src/plugins/vuetify.ts** which looks like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const vuetify = new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#3f51b5",
        secondary: "#b0bec5",
        anchor: "#8c9eff",
      },
    },
  },
});
  
export default vuetify;
```

Then in my **main.ts** I have done this:

```
import "./registerServiceWorker";

import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

import vuetify from "@/plugins/vuetify";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h: any) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

But when I try to launch my app, even though it compiles, when I navigate to my component I see it states:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-btn> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <HelloWorld> at src/components/HelloWorld.vue
       <Home> at src/views/Home.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the plugin was not installed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the webpack [vuetify-loader](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader).

```js
// webpack.config.js

const { VuetifyLoaderPlugin } = require('vuetify-loader')

exports.plugins.push(
  new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()
)
```

---

Or you can import vuetify like this if you don't use the custom webpack loader:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const vuetify = new Vuetify({});

export default vuetify;
```

Comment: isn't that bottom answer exactly what I am doing?

Comment: No, the import is `from 'vuetify'` instead of `from 'vuetify/lib'`, and it includes the css as well. But good you figured out your problem :)